# Rotation matrix in Matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix, gyroscope, rotational-matrices

I am going to rotate from one frame to another one with rotation matrix. goal of program is to make my Gyro parallel to earth, it means output vector should has first two numbers zero and third one -9.81. 
Codes:

```
vs1 = 1;
vs2 = -0.003;
vs3 = -9.808;

vst = [vs1 vs2 vs3]';

alpha = (acosd(vs1/sqrt(vs1^2+vs2^2)));

gama = (acosd(vs2/sqrt(vs1^2+vs2^2)));

beta  = (acosd(vs3/sqrt(vs1^2+vs2^2+vs3^2)));
R1 = [(cosd(gama)*cosd(beta)*cosd(alpha))-(sind(gama)*sind(alpha)) (cosd(gama)*cosd(beta)*sind(al)+sind(gama)*cosd(al)) (-cosd(gama)*sind(beta));((-sind(gama)*cosd(beta)*cosd(alpha))-cosd(gama)*sind(alpha)) ((-sind(gama)*cosd(beta)*sind(alpha))+(cosd(gama)*cosd(alpha))) sind(gama)*sind(beta);sind(beta)*cosd(alpha) sind(beta)*sind(alpha) cosd(beta)];
disp (R1*vst)
```

result for vs1,vs2 and vs3 is : -0.00599, 0.0000359 and 9.858845622079866. first, I can not understand why program give me positive Z and why it does not make first two numbers zero?

thanks in advance

Comment: It's either a bug or a misconception. In both cases you are the best person to solve it.Try to decompose your code in smaller parts and check each one carefully. The line defining R1 is dangerously too long for instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a bug in your code. There are two places where I think the variable "al" should actually be "alpha" if I'm following your code correctly.

But your code also generates alpha = 90 and gama = 180 for those inputs. All you're going to do is flip the axes to within machine precision with those inputs, so it's not going to achieve the results you're looking for.

1) Are you sure the input vector is correct? Why would gravity have a value near X=1 if you're nearly vertical (Z = -9.808)?

Comment: you are completly right. it should not be 1. but anyway for any numbers for vs1,if I put negative number (for vs2 ) result is not good.

Comment: Given the angles alpha and gama that are generated, I would first ask whether or not they are being calculated correctly. Have you tried an input like vst = [1,1,1]' to see if it generates a reasonable set of angles?